# Only Login Work with switch language in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I use two languages in my website. In the first, I could switch languages easy but I don't know what happened.

Now I can switch language if I login (auth) but if I login as  guest I can't switch languages anymore.

This is my route:

**// Routes**

```
Route::get('locale', function () {
    return \App::getLocale();                                            
});

Route::get('locale/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    \Session::put('locale', $locale); 
    return redirect()->back();
});

Route::post('/language-chooser', 'LanguageController@changeLanguage');

Route::post('/language/', array(
    'before' => 'csrf',
    'as' => 'language-chooser',
    'uses' => 'LanguageController@changeLanguage'));
```

**// Controller**

```
public function changeLanguage(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax())
    {
        $request->session()->put('locale',$request->locale);
        $request->session()->flash('alert-success',
            ('app.locale_change_success'));
    }
}
```

**// Middlware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( Session::has('locale')) {
        $locale = Session::get('locale', Config::get('app.locale'));    
    } else {
        $locale = 'en';
    }

    App::setLocale($locale);

    return $next($request);
} 
}
```

**// View**

```
<select id="LanguageSwitcher" >
    <option value="en" <?php $cuRRlocal = Config::get('app.locale'); 
        echo ($cuRRlocal == 'en' ? "selected" : "") ?>>English</option>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <option value="ar" <?php $cuRRlocal = Config::get('app.locale'); 
        echo ($cuRRlocal == 'ar' ? "selected" : "") ?> >Arabic</option>
</select>
```

---

when i try change language and i not authenticated nothing happened

i elso did this but nothing happend

```
public function __construct()
     {
      $this->middleware('auth',['except'=>['changeLanguage']]);

       }
```

Comment: `can't switch languages` - what happens when you try?

Comment: when i try change language and i not authenticated nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

If you can switch language when logged in as auth, then I think you have protected the `LanguageController` with the auth middleware, can you describe what happen when you want to change language and are not authenticated?.

Just check the language controller constructor if it's having the auth middleware. and if that is the case, then you will want remove the following code to a different controller that is accessible to both the authenticated user and unauthenticated users.

```
public function changeLanguage(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax())
    {
        $request->session()->put('locale',$request->locale);
        $request->session()->flash('alert-success',
            ('app.locale_change_success'));
    }
}
```

Comment: when i try change language and i not authenticated nothing happened

i elso did this but nothing happend 

    public function __construct()
         {
          $this->middleware('auth',['except'=>['changeLanguage']]);
                                                                       
           }

Answer (score 0):

I Fix Problem by Add
@csrf 
before pages

cuz i was write this line 
Route::post('/language/', array( 'before' => 'csrf', 'as' => 'language-chooser', 'uses' => 'LanguageController@changeLanguage')); // Controller